# File replication program for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync, network-attached-storage, snapshot

For my disaster recovery plan I am looking for a free/open source file replication program which could copy all files including open/busy files to a remote server. Would appreciate any suggestions or help.

Comment: "I would like to have some food. Any suggestions?" .. please be more specific. How much data are we talking about? Should this be a constant replication or done couple times a day? You have already mentioned one possible piece of software in tags (`rsync`) but we need to know more about your needs.

Answer (score 2):

For all the static and slow changing content closed files etc something like [rsync](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) will do. The open and busy files would have to be evaluated on a case by case basis as for example how you deal with a database is entirely different from how you deal with a plain busy file.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use http://www.logicwreck.com/index.php/2012/06/16/ftp-synchronization-script/, this is a simple script which will synchronize any files or directories created/updated/deleted in a directory on your server with a ftp server.

Comment: Link to file is restricted.

Comment: Use https://github.com/logicwreck/solutions/tree/ftp_synchronize for now - we're doing some changes.